# How can I get a WSL window with full colour support in Windows GUI Emacs?

Tags: terminal, emacs, text-editors, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ansi

How can I get WSL [Windows Sub-system for Linux] to run in a window on Windows GUI Emacs?

The only way I can do it so far is to enter a subshell in either emacs shell or term cmd by entering the `wsl` command, and even then, there is no background ANSI coloring, though the foreground coloring appears to be working.

The following is an attempt at directly spawning a `wsl.exe` child process.

```
(if (eq system-type 'windows-nt)

    (setq explicit-shell-file-name "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe")

    (defun run-wsl ()
        (interactive)
        (let ((shell-file-name "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe"))
            (ansi-term "*wsl.exe*")
        )
    )
)
```

Error message under mode bar: `Spawning child process: Invalid argument`

---

Edit 1:

Note that I am asking how to get WSL in Emacs, not Emacs in WSL.

Comment: Like this https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225

Comment: @Biswapriyo That is Emacs in WSL, not WSL in Emacs.

Comment: Does Emacs even have full colour support in the first place? Last time I tried it on Linux, the built-in terminal could only show 8 colors and the background format looked wonky.

Comment: @grawity I'm not sure, but more importantly, I don't get any background support, but do get 8-color foreground support. At the very least I would like background support.